# One LED bulb in chandelier turns off after two seconds

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I have a chandelier with 5 bulbs that is hooked to a dimmer. We switched the bulbs out to LED and when we turn on the light, after a couple seconds, one of the bulbs will turn off. It's not always the same bulb. A different bulb will turn off each time. Tried replacing the dimmer with a new LED compatible dimmer, but the same thing happens.

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Does this happen even when the dimmer is turned all the way up?

Comment: Verify that the bulbs themselves are dimmer compatible

Comment: Connect an ordinary switch - that will cost you about $ 1 if you don't have an extra lying around, and see if everything works. If the lights work consistently with a regular switch then you are having dimmer vs. LED issues, *even if both the dimmer and the LEDs say they are compatible*. If the lights have the same problem with a regular switch then you have a loose wire somewhere in the chandelier.

Comment: If you put 1 incandescent back in, do the other 4 LEDs behave as expected?

Comment: What make and model are the bulbs and dimmer in question?

Comment: Yes, it does this with the dimmer all the way up. Yes, the bulbs are dimmable bulbs. One additional item, there is no neutral run to the dimmer location. I have a feeling this might be more of the problem than anything else.